# Whiteboard for angular 2

Tags: angular, canvas, whiteboard

I want to have a whiteboard in my website, where I'm developing it's front-end with angular 2, and I searched for whiteboard many times and the best thing I found is Literally Canvas but it doesn't have enough features, for example I want the whiteboard has ruler with centimeter and inch units and I want to draw different shapes likes flowers and animals and also save the result as png.

Comment: You can refer http://szimek.github.io/signature_pad/ and check this https://github.com/szimek/signature_pad

Comment: @ Abhishek Ekaanth  thanks for your help but it doesn't have enough features.

Comment: @SAM did you find any solution? or did you end up using canvas?

Comment: unfortunately I ended up using canvas

Answer (score 1):

You can try my whiteboard demo here:
https://vrobbi-whiteboard.herokuapp.com/?roomID=27223&audio=true

It is free and was done with node.js on server side and with socket.io library 
on both sides.

There is also an option for a webrtc audio call.
I can create a new whiteboard with the features you need if you like it. For reference the source can be found [here](https://github.com/vrobbi/whiteboard).